# How can I apply a predicate to a set?

Tags: vdm++, vdm-sl

Say I have a set, `S = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` (the contents don't really matter)

I can say `forall x in set S & x mod 2 = 0` but that will give me a boolean answer - are all the numbers in it even? What if I want to see all members of the set for which `x mod 2 = 0` is true?

What's the syntax for applying a predicate to it? How can I filter for odd numbers, even numbers, numbers above/below 3.5 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax, it'll return the members of the set for which the predicate is true:

```
{x | x in set S & x mod 2 = 0}
```

Comment: Lovely, missed that part in the language manual. I'd use curly braces though.